# Trouble sending an array to a model in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

**What I have:**

A Model like this:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SkipUpdates { get; set; }
}
```

A controller method like this:

```
public ActionResult GetProductUpdates(ProductModel productModel)
{
   return View("AddEdit");
}
```

Not doing anything for now just want to make sure that data from JS comes in correctly.

The JS:

```
function productModel() {
    this.productName = "";
    this.SkipUpdates = [];
}
```

Filling the model and AJAX:

```
var newProductModel = new productModel();

var options = $('#AdditionalSkipDates  option');
        var skipDates = [];

        options.each(function (i, option) {
            skipDates[i] = $(option).text();
        });

newProductModel.productName = "ABC";
newProductModel.SkipUpdates = skipDates;

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlToGetProductSchedule,
        data: newProductModel,
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function () {

    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert("Something went wrong!!!");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

AdditonalSkip dates is a listbox with a bunch of dates in it.

**What's happening:**

The SkipUpdates array does have values which I can see in the browser's console.
Put a breakpoint in the controller and it hits the method.
The SkipUpdates value is null.

**What's not happening:**

How do I get the array to come-into the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your not adding indexers to the collection values. You can look at stringifying the data (JSON.stringify()`) and/or using the `traditional: true,` option. but why are you posting back all options anyway (as opposed to just the selected values?)

Comment: Stephen it does'nt matter if all options or just the selected are posted. It is the array that will be posted.

Comment: Yes, and the array will include all options and if id id work, you will have no way of knowing which options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify the object before sending it:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlToGetProductSchedule,
        data: JSON.stringify(newProductModel),
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function () {

    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert("Something went wrong!!!");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
```